# get post parameters in zend framework in "put" method

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, put, post-parameter

I am getting get parameters using this

```
$this->params()->fromQuery('KEY');
```

I found two way to get POST parameters

```
//first way
$this->params()->fromPost('KEY', null);

//second way
$this->getRequest()->getPost();
```

Both of this working in "POST" method but now in a "PUT" method if I pass values as a post parameters.

How I can get post parameters in "PUT" method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to read the request body and parse it, something like this:

```
$putParams = array();
parse_str($this->getRequest()->getContent(), $putParams);
```

This will parse all params into the `$putParams`-array, so you can access it like you would access the super globals `$_POST` or `$_GET`. For instance:

```
// Get the parameter named 'id'
$id = $putParams['id'];

// Loop over all params
foreach($putParams as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Put-param ' . $key . ' = ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: what this will return ? and How to get specific param from the list of parameters ?

Answer (score 9):

I guess the right way of doing that is by using **Zend_Controller_Plugin_PutHandler**:

```
// you can put this code in your projects bootstrap
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->registerPlugin(new Zend_Controller_Plugin_PutHandler());
```

and then you can get your params via **getParams()**

```
foreach($this->getRequest()->getParams() as $key => $value) {
    ...
}
```

or simply

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam("myvar");
```

Comment: it gives an error that "front controller not found". Do i need to import any file to use this?

Comment: it should be included by your Zend's autoloader. If it is not, I suppose you should include Zend\Constroller\Front and Zend\Controller\Plugin\PutHandler into your code

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble using PUT data sent from AngularJS and found the best way was to use a custom Zend plugin

```
class Web_Mvc_Plugin_JsonPutHandler extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        if (!$request instanceof Zend_Controller_Request_Http) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->_request->isPut()) {
            $putParams = json_decode($this->_request->getRawBody());
            $request->setParam('data', $putParams);
        }
    }
}
```

Which can then be accesses via `getParams` as a PHP object

```
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParam('data');
    $id = $data->id;
```